# Are Stochastic Processes taught at undergraduate level in top universities?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, education

In my country there is no university where you can learn this subject so I am interested in how students in developed countries are taught

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, for experience, that there were such in Poland, the Netherlands, and the UK. The level and the content, of course, vary depending on the nature of the curse (pure or applied).